# Making a headless eclipse application with optional UI interface

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have been planning to create an eclipse application which needs to be a console application by default but have the UI (window/menu/views) as optional.

I need to run the application from command line for most of the time, but need to take the console application take command to enable the UI when I need it.

Can anyone direct me to proper resource how to configure these sort of application through eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that this can be done. It should be simple enough to choose console / GUI as the application starts, but once it is started I doubt that it can be changed.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do what you are referring? like passing argument during application start to select command line or gui version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done once the application has started.

For a 3.x compatibility mode RCP implementing `IApplication` you could check the command line arguments for something to tell you which type of start is required in the `start` method:

```
@Override
public Object start(final IApplicationContext context) throws Exception
{
  String [] args = (String [])context.getArguments().get(IApplicationContext.APPLICATION_ARGS);

  // TODO scan args for an option telling you which start is required

  // TODO If GUI required call PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench in the usual way
  // TODO otherwise do console app
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, much appreciated.